# In selenium webdriver what is manage() [driver.manage()]

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

One of my friend has asked me a question that below is the code to maximize the window.

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

what is `manage()` here?

As per my knowledge `manage()` is the abstract method.

Please anyone explain the meaning of below line, how we are able to use `maximize()` method by writing below code:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: What is driver? Firefox? Also you do not need `manage()` there, it works too: `driver.window_maximize()`, it may be an old method to use `manage()` I guess.

Comment: @hzleonardo driver.window_maximize() is for python..the OP has requested for java version.

Comment: Oh, ok. I didn't see anything mention to be java in question, so...

Answer (score 3):

manage() returns an instance of underlying implementation of Interface `Options` which could be EventFiringOptions / RemoteWebDriverOptions. Options give you access to browser's menu. 
JavaDocs excerpts for Options:

> An interface for managing stuff you would do in a browser menu

Answer (score 3):

- Based on your question- driver is an instance of concrete class which implements WebDriver interface.
- manage() method returns an *"Option interface"* referred to as **WebDriver.Options**
- When you type **driver.manage().** -> gives you list of methods to access.
- Ex. you can call a method window()->**driver.manage().window()**.
  This would further return the interface for managing window referred to as **WebDriver.Window** interface for managing current window.
- *WebDriver.Window* interface has a method called **maximize()**.
  It can be called using following code: **driver.manage().window().maximize()**. This would maximize current window if not already maximized.

Hope the details were helpful.Keep learning.

Answer (score 0):

driver.manage() is a method that returns instance of options interface, now the options interface has method window() that returns instance of window interface, this window interface has method maximize() which maximizes the window.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Manage is a abstract method where it return Option[I].
Option[I] has following Abstract method
1)window
2)timeout
3)cookies related

window returns Window[I].
window [I] has following abstract method
minimize
maximize
fullscreen
position
size

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).